# properly clearing whole AngularJS ui-grid chart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm calling these codes at the beginning of my $scope.generateReport function hoping it would clear the data that is currently shown on the grid once I click the button. Unfortunately, it's not clearing it.

I was thinking that by setting it with undefined values, ui-grid would automatically refresh itself thereby clearing the whole grid.

```
$scope.generateReport = function() {

    $scope.gridOptions = {};
    $scope.gridOptions.data = undefined;
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = undefined;
    $scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
    ........
}

// on my html template, I have a button that has an ng-click
// ng-click="generateReport()"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a plunker with an example of one way to do it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1anj7jyPHz3LAXoir4E?p=preview

```
  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.myData.length=0;
  }
```